# Running 1st android app in eclipse

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App crash in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277856/app-crash-in-eclipse)

I am new in android app devlopment & I have instaled

- Android sdk tools Rev 20.0.3
- Android sdk Platform-tools Rev 3
- Android 2.3.3(API 10) sdk platform  rev 2
- Ssmples for sdk api 10 rev 1
- ADT Plugin 20.0.3

I created a new project which generated a Hello World
Error I get when I try to run is `that device not connected...`

Next error I get `your project includes errors please fix them before running your application`

I have also created a AVD

Comment: See your project explorer window. It has any error or not?

Comment: You are asking the same question again..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277856/app-crash-in-eclipse

Comment: Please make sure that your questions are well formatted and in clear language. Avoid emotions and pleading for help. It is a waste of time for all to read stuff not related to your problem. Also please copy paste errors, instead of interpreting it. I have edited your question for improved readability.

Comment: how could I check that my project explorer window has any error or not Spk?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you have the right Android Lib inside your project.
Otherwise right click on the project then Properties->Android Project Build Target and select one.

**Be sure that the AVD you created has an API level >= the Project API level.**

Comment: yes I have checked that both the api level are 10

Answer (score 0):

Your need a lot to learn before you get started with first Android project.
First of all have a thorough study of getting started with Android concepts.

1. You need to integrate the android sdk with the IDE (Eclipse say).
2. Install ADT plugin.
3. Need too create an AVD.
4. Project API level should be same as that of AVD.

And little more: start study https://developer.android.com/training/index.html, it's the best training guide.

Comment: i have set the sdk location on eclipse by  
window>preference>Android>
I have installed ADT PLUGIN 20.0.3

Comment: Check for the errors in Window->Show View->Console and Window->Show View->LogCat for the errors and if possible, post the errors here..

Answer (score 0):

You Probably tried to run the xml.
For the first start, be sure to right click on your project and select Run As... --> Android Application.

to fix the "your project contains errors" : When trying to run an xml a something like myactivity_out.xml gets created. delete that.